# Foreign Language Issues while using PHP to generate JSON files

Tags: php, mysql, json, unicode

I have a MySQL database which contains some texts, some of the texts are in foreign languages.  When I tried to use PHP to generate a JSON using those contents.  I get question marks and nulls for those fields.

If I use MySQL Workbench to retrieve those fields, they are displayed in foreign language correctly.  Anyway I can fix this?  Here are the codes I use to generate the JSON file.

```
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(json_encode(array("error"=>mysql_error())));
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode(array("T"=>$arr));
exit;
```

Comment: How are you running PHP to see the ? and NULs?  From an ASCII command line?

Comment: What character set encoding is being used in MySQL itself?

Comment: You need to maintain the same character set throughout the entire pipeline, or convert as needed. If your DB is utf-8 but your http connection is using iso8859, then you're going to get garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Use **utf8_encode** function to encode everything you bring from the database to UTF8.

Make sure all your files are encoded the same way and in your HTML add:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

At the begining of the `<head>` tag